# "Drawing room" or "sitting room"?

Tags: word-choice, adjectives, british-english, class-based-usage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What’s a reception room / parlor / parlour / drawing room?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/31644/whats-a-reception-room-parlor-parlour-drawing-room)

Please consider the following room:

The house is a late Victorian townhouse. The room (A) has a size of about 40 sqm, or 400 sq ft., a nice but not elaborate chimneypiece with sofas in front of it, a plastered ceiling, grand piano, a few mahogany pieces. A door (regular, not double or sliding) leads to the dining room, another to the hall.

No television set, which is in another, smaller room (B) upstairs, used for watching television and as a spare guest room. But it's in room (A) that the family sit and read or play board games, in other words, room (A) isn't just for formal entertaining of guests once in a while.

For this sort of room, would upper and upper-middle class Brits say "drawing room", "sitting room" or something else?

Would it be different if the room were used in the same way, but had a desk and lots of bookshelves along the walls?

(I know that there are regional differences and the like, that especially in America, that would be a living room, that many Brits wouldn't fuss and call any lounge a lounge, and that Mrs Bucket would call any sort of "main room" a drawing room, that's why I specifically ask about uppers and upper-middles.)

Comment: 40 square meters is closer to 430 square feet.

Comment: [**drawing room**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/drawing+room) - *A shortening of withdrawing room, the room to which the ladies withdrew, leaving the men to smoking and drinking.* This is general reference.

Comment: @Robusto: Nobody *but nobody* uses "drawing room" any more. Ordinary people use *day room, family room, lounge, sitting room,* etc., and estate agents call them *reception rooms*, but you only really find *drawing rooms* (along with *parlours*) in Victorian *fiction*, not actual houses.

Comment: @Fumble: Well, he did say it was "a late Victorian townhouse."

Comment: @Rudi: There aren't enough actual "upper class" people left in Britain to be anything other than a dated stereotype. So the way this virtually non-existent group of people are portrayed in fiction tells you little about actual usage. But I think most "upper middle class" people would probably call your room the "sitting room".

Comment: @Robusto: I actually had a house like OP's a decade or so ago - but being "*lower* middle class", we usually just called ours the *front room*. It wouldn't have made much sense to call it the *sitting room*, since we hardly ever used it except when entertaining up-market guests we wanted to impress. Mostly it just got dusted once a week!

Comment: @Fumble: You see "front room" and "parlor" used a lot in the South, esp. in the parts where they're trying to maintain a genteel atmosphere.

Comment: _Sitting room_ will do for many kinds of house. FumbleFingers is right about _drawing room_. Another term (alongside _reception room_), favoured by estate agents is _lounge_. If you have a really grand house, you will have none of these, but rooms known as 'The Red Room' or 'The Music Room' or 'The Ballroom'.

Comment: Everybody: thanks. Robusto: Yes, I meant the house was from the 1890s, and I suppose it would have been called a drawing room back then by middle as well as upper-class people, but don't know about today. FumbleFingers, I see your point about the vanishing upper class, but there are certainly many big country houses left, and I thought that drawing rooms there were still unselfconsiously called thus. (I might be wrong there.) My question was only if somebody upper-class would call a room of the sort I described in a townhouse as a drawing room today, or if this would sound out of place.

Comment: @BarrieEngland From this side of the pond, *sitting room* sounds fine even if it isn’t common, whereas *drawing room* has a musty-unto-death smell about it, or at least of something that’s escaped its prison in the cellars of Wardour Street. Sometimes people these days will say the [*great room*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_room).

Comment: I'd avoid the *"musty-unto-death"* (nice one, @tchrist!) overtones of *drawing room* and *parlour*. As I recall, when people used to discuss what we should call the various rooms in our swanky (to us) new house after we moved in, quite a few thought that one should be the *sitting room*. But we saw it as a synonym of *lounge* (which we used for the main "communal evening room", as opposed to the communal *day room*). So we went for *front room*, even though a few people thought that was a bit "plebby".

Comment: @Robusto: I take it you mean *parlor* is still used by genteel Texans in Southern US. Which kinda fits my perception, but I mainly get that from movies where they invariably portray such people as fading relics of a bygone age. I find it hard to imagine a wealthy Surrey stockbroker saying "Let's go through to the parlour" after dinner today. But we ourselves probably said *"Shall we **retire** to the drawing room/parlour"* at least once or twice (facetiously, since we knew we were parvenus! :).

Comment: @Fumble: No, certainly not Texas. I'm talking about genteel (formerly, as in antebellum) aristocratic southerners from places like Augusta, GA. I used to have a girlfriend from there whose mother was quite was vocal about there being "nothing but trash" in Texas.

Comment: @Robusto: Ah. You'd be far more familiar than me with the relevant region then. I tend to lump everything South of Oklahoma/Tennessee/Virginia together as "The Deep South", populated mainly by Southern Belles and closet Ku-Klux-Clanners. I know that's an appalling stereotype, for which I do apologise (but Hollywood are at least partly to blame! :)

Comment: @Fumble: Well, I'm sure you'd be appalled if I conflated Dorset with Surrey and Salisbury with Yorkshire and East Anglia.

Comment: @Robusto: Actually, I'm not sure I would. Myself and many of my compatriots have very different "stereotypes" for Liverpudlians, Mancunians, Geordies, etc. But we're so small compared to the US that I tend to feel "flattered" if an American even distinguishes Northern/Southern English. Hollywood usually just makes a two-way split - *imperialist/la-di-dah English* on one side, and *oppressed-but-honest-and-hard-working Irish/Scots/Welsh* on the other (whose accents they freely combine and interchange! :).

Answer (score 1):

I think your question can be answered by [this question and answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/31644/whats-a-reception-room-parlor-parlour-drawing-room), but having said that, it depends on the intended use of the room. We had a sitting room in a house I own, but we more often than not called it the front room because that's where it was.

If you intend to use it with your family, then it might be a family room. My initial instinct would be that you want it to be a parlo(u)r, or a room where you would invite guests to sit and visit.

Comment: I may be wrong about this, but I have the impression *parlor* is still used quite naturally by some Americans even today, whereas *parlour* practically vanished from Britain after WW2.